# Adding more points on axis of Matlab plot

Tags: matlab

I used the `semiologx` command to generate these two plots, but I need the plot to show more reference values on the X axis. 
[image]

How can this be accomplished in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your plot was generated by `semilogx`, not `semilogy`. Anyway you can set the values on the `x` axis (called "ticks") using (for example):

```
set(gca, 'xtick', [1 10 100 1000])
```

The 1st argument is the axis handle you wish to change, in this example I just use `gca` which stands for "get current axes", and returns the currently active axes.

Comment: OP said `semilogx`, but Horchler edited it to `semilogy`. Funny that googling "MATLAB xtick" does not get you this syntax as a first documentation result; I knew it was `xtick`, just not the exact syntax...

Comment: @Adriaan It does for me.